# Cleaner SQL statement by reducing redundancy of repeating column names

Tags: sql, postgresql

I find myself repeating to write column names across various parts in an SQL statement. One example is below, which I need help to see if there is a better way to write. The list of columns is being repeated, firstly in GROUP BY clause, secondly in SELECT during the UNION.

Coming from programming background, I'd think this can be defined as a template somewhere, and reused across. I'd go to the manual if someone could help to point me to the right way.

I am only showing UNION of two tables here, but in reality I have to do UNION for about 10 company reports. I am currently using Postgres 10.

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW staging.journal_2017_total AS
(
    WITH 
    company_1 AS (
        SELECT 'COMPANY 1' AS source, year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name, sum(amount) AS amount
        FROM staging.journal_company_1
        GROUP BY year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name
    ),

    company_2 AS (
        SELECT 'COMPANY 2' as source, year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name, sum(amount) AS amount
        FROM staging.journal_company_2
        GROUP BY year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name
    )

    SELECT source, year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name, amount
    FROM company_1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT source, year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name, amount
    FROM company_2
)
```

Comment: I am wondering why you have separate tables when the structure of each of the tables appears to be identical, or at least very similar.  If you had all data in a single table, then you might not need to take a `UNION` at all.

Comment: there's a rigorous checking at ETL process, and they do it company by company. there are different business owners for each company, accountable to their own verification.

Answer (score 0):

They are all CTEs that you define, so you could be careful to be sure al have the same columns in the same order and write:

```
SELECT *
FROM company_1
UNION ALL
SELECT *
FROM company_2
```

However, copying and pasting the list of columns does not seem overly cumbersome.

Comment: it's not so much about writing it, but the mental clutter of seeing such redundancy.

Comment: @idazuwaika . . . SQL doesn't have a concept of anything like macros that would simplify this.

Answer (score 0):

would this work, reduces the number of times you specify columns. 
will break if not the same columns in table, so somewhat prone to fail in this regards.

```
SELECT source, year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,
               cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name, sum(amount) AS amount
        FROM 
        (
          SELECT 'COMPANY 1' AS source, x.*
          FROM staging.journal_company_1 x
          union all
          SELECT 'COMPANY 2' AS source, x.*
          FROM staging.journal_company_2 x
        )
        GROUP BY source/*add this */,year, month_no, year_month, profit_center, revenue_class,cust_acc_name, billing_acc_name
```